# Am I protected in post from "html form" with new pdo just converted code?

Tags: php, sql, security, pdo

I think, I am missing some vulnerabilities in my code. 
Light me, I've just converted my script in PDO and this is for safe and not only!

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
exit;
}

?>
<?php $utilizator = $fgmembersite->UserFullName() ?>

<?php require ("../SQL.php");

### De aici am setat creearea directoarelor pentru poze ###
$model         = mysql_real_escape_string("$_POST[model]");
$marca         = mysql_real_escape_string("$_POST[marca]");

 mkdir ("\\server\\htdocs\\panou\\poze\\{$marca}/{$model}", 0777, true);
$director_poza = ("poze/{$marca}/{$model}/");    
$numetmp_poza  = $_FILES['numepoza1']['name'];
$numepoza1     = $director_poza.$numetmp_poza;
$numetmp_poza  = $_FILES['numepoza2']['name'];
$numepoza2     = $director_poza.$numetmp_poza;
$numetmp_poza  = $_FILES['numepoza3']['name'];
$numepoza3     = $director_poza.$numetmp_poza;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['numepoza1']['tmp_name'], $numepoza1))
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['numepoza2']['tmp_name'], $numepoza2))
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['numepoza3']['tmp_name'], $numepoza3))
{
list($width,$height,$type,$attr)= getimagesize($numepoza1);
switch($type)
{
case 1:
$ext = ".gif"; break;
case 2:
$ext = ".jpg"; break;
case 3:
$ext = ".png"; break;
default:
echo "Format foto neacceptat";
} }### Gata creeare director si upload poze ###

$insertie = "INSERT INTO modele 
(id, marca, model, utilizator, despre, data, data_luna, data_zi, img1, img2, img3, doi_g, trei_g, patru_g, info_ecran, rezolutie_ecran, multitouch_ecran, protectie_ecran, sunet_sonerii, sunet_mainilibere, sunet_mufa_jack, memorie_card, mcard_tip,   mcard_capacitate,intern_memorie, date_gprs, date_edge, date_viteze, date_wifi, date_bt,   date_nfc, date_usb, camera_spate, camera_fata, camera_tehnologii, camera_video,   performanta_os,performanta_chipset, performanta_cpu, performanta_cpu_core, performanta_cpu_tip, performanta_rami, performanta_gpu, performanta_senzori, performanta_gps, performanta_java, altele_radio, altele_mesajerie, altele_filme,  baterie_autonomie, baterie_mAh, baterie_convorbire, SEO_cuvinte_cheie)
  VALUES
  ('',        '$_POST[marca]','$_POST[model]','$utilizator','$_POST[despre]','$_POST[data]','$_POST[data_luna]','$_POST[data_zi]',
'$numepoza1','$numepoza2','$numepoza3','$_POST[doi_g]',
'$_POST[trei_g]',
'$_POST[patru_g]',
'$_POST[info_ecran]',
'$_POST[rezolutie_ecran]',
'$_POST[multitouch_ecran]',
'$_POST[protectie_ecran]',
'$_POST[sunet_sonerii]',
'$_POST[sunet_mainilibere]',
'$_POST[sunet_mufa_jack]',
'$_POST[memorie_card]',
'$_POST[mcard_tip]',
'$_POST[mcard_capacitate]',
'$_POST[intern_memorie]',
'$_POST[date_gprs]',
'$_POST[date_edge]',
'$_POST[date_viteze]',
'$_POST[date_wifi]',
'$_POST[d ate_bt]',
'$_POST[date_nfc]',
'$_POST[date_usb]',
'$_POST[camera_spate]',
'$_POST[camera_fata]',
'$_POST[camera_tehnologii]',
'$_POST[camera_video]',
'$_POST[performanta_os]',
'$_POST[performanta_chipset]',
'$_POST[performanta_cpu]',
'$_POST[pe rformanta_cpu_core]',
'$_POST[performanta_cpu_tip]',
'$_POST[performanta_rami]',
'$_POST[perfo rmanta_gpu]',
'$_POST[performanta_senzori]',
'$_POST[performanta_gps]',
'$_POST[performanta_java]',
'$_POST[altele_radio]',
'$_POST[altele_mesajerie]',
'$_POST[altele_filme]',
'$_POST[baterie_autonomie]',
'$_POST[baterie_mAh]',
'$_POST[baterie_convorbire]',
'$_POST[SEO_cuvinte_cheie]')"; 

if ($dbh->query($insertie)) 
{
print '<center><h1>Telefonul/Tableta a fost publicat(a) cu succes!</h1><br />
Vei fi redirectionat in cateva momente inspre adaugarea unui nou model de tableta sau         telefon!</center>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=adauga-tableta-tel.php"/>'; 
}
 else(mysql_error())     
?>
```

Please come with some help not links to read about.

Comment: All these and more have to be escaped! '$_POST[date_nfc]',
'$_POST[date_usb]',
'$_POST[camera_spate]',
'$_POST[camera_fata]',
'$_POST[camera_tehnologii]',
'$_POST[camera_video]',
'$_POST[performanta_os]',
'$_POST[performanta_chipset]',
'$_POST[performanta_cpu]',
'$_POST[pe rformanta_cpu_core]',
'$_POST[performanta_cpu_tip]',
'$_POST[performanta_rami]',
'$_POST[perfo rmanta_gpu]',
'$_POST[performanta_senzori]',
'$_POST[performanta_gps]',
'$_POST[performanta_java]',
'$_POST[altele_radio]',
'$_POST[altele_mesajerie]',
'$_POST[altele_filme]',
'$_POST[baterie_autonomie]',
'$_POST[baterie_mAh]'...

Comment: but how? an litle example please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should be using pdo's `prepare` statements

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

I'm not gonna rewrite all that code for you, but thats a good place to start.

As far as saftey goes, IIRC, pdo only allows you to execute one query at a time, so sql injection is a bit harder. But i would still go with preparing because you are pulling all that data out of the post

for example, from the url above

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, color, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND color = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: U dont have to write the code for me, but please can u just make a litle example in my case?